# JavaMail stylish mail

Tags: image, header, jakarta-mail, footer, multipart

I'm looking for a way to send a stylish email with javamail.
When I say stylish I mean a header (image) then some text on the middle, and then a footer with some information. It should be like a standard welcome template mail that many companies use.

I've tried sending messages with attached images and so on with MultiPart, but what I'm looking for seems to be more advanced, and I can't find any good example on the web.

Just so you understand what I mean here's an example image: [image: email with header and footere]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Start with this JavaMail FAQ entry:

- [How do I send HTML mail that includes images?](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javamail/faq/index.html#sendmpr)